# OpenJson throws error in sql server programming

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have below table. I want this products table to be updated based on @source json

product_id, product_name,total_sales

[image]

OPENJSON gives me key and value , but how do i explicitly set column names for my json

and also while doing join i need to skip electronics then only it will do join

This code throws error as key not found

```
begin 
declare @source nvarchar(max) = '{"electronics.tv":200,"electronics.mobile":1000}'

 UPDATE p
 SET p.total_sales = u.value
 products p
 INNER JOIN 
 OPENJSON(@source,'$') AS u
 ON p.product_name = u.key

end
```

It thows error as incorrect syntax near key

Can someone help me here

Comment: `KEY` is a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), it must be delimit identified.

Comment: *"how do i explicitly set column names for my json"* In the `WITH` clause, such as shown in [example 3 of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#example-4---combine-relational-rows-and-json-elements-with-cross-apply)